# Discard 2 cards from a deck and distribute the remaining 50 cards to 5 people. What is the probability that one player gets 4 Aces?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, card-games

I calculate a case that no Ace card was removed, so we have $5 \times \frac{10C4}{50C4} \approx 0.004559$. For every other cases, there is no way to get 4 Aces, so the probability is 0.

The correct answer is $\approx 0.00388$, what am I missing here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Letting the players be labeled as player1, player2, etc... to be clear are you asking for the probability that *player 1* gets all four aces?  Or any player getting the four aces?  There are *five* people or four people?  What is the $4$ in the front of $4\times \frac{10C4}{50C4}$ doing there?  What is the chance that we are actually in the case that no ace was removed and where was this used in your calculation?

Comment: For a simplification... rather than discarding two cards and *then* dealing out what remains to the five players... it can be far easier to *first* deal out to the five players and *then* the two cards that remain get discarded.  This does not change any of the randomness of what people end up with in their hands and is far easier to calculate.

Comment: Please insert the question also in the text, not only in the title. I suppose that $10C4$ is the number of combinations of four cards at ten places. In this case, the answer is$$5\times \frac{10C4}{52C4}=5\cdot\frac{10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot 7}{52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot 49}=\frac{9\cdot 8}{52\cdot 51\cdot 7}\approx 0.0038784744667097608274078862\dots\ . $$

Comment: @JMoravitz I was wrong, actually it's 5 there

Comment: @dan_fulea Would you please explain why we have 52C4 instead of 50C4? Thank you!

Comment: @CNg Because we make the simplification that the discarding of the two cards occurs after the dealing.  That in fact all sets of four positions for the aces within the deck *as a whole before the discard* are equally likely to have occurred.  If you insist on discarding first, then you need to *condition* on being in the case that the aces were not among those discarded and conditioning on this case involves not only the probabilities once we are in the case itself but also the probability of *getting to that case in the first place*.

Comment: That is to say, we could have worded the answer as $\left(\color{red}{\dfrac{\binom{50}{4}}{\binom{52}{4}}}\right)\cdot5\cdot\dfrac{\binom{10}{4}}{\binom{50}{4}}$ which you will notice the $\binom{50}{4}$'s cancel where here the fraction in red is what you missed and is the probability of having been in the case of no aces being discarded in the first place.

Comment: @JMoravitz It really helps, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could not fit as a comment, so it is an answer. The counting problem is equivalent to the following one. Consider all permutations of the numbers $1,2,3,\dots,52$, we will write such a permutation as a "tuple", e.g. $(9,7,44,1,51,4,6,2,9,10,11,\dots,232)$. We distribute the cards to the five players in the order of the taken permuation, so the first player gets the first ten cards, in this example the cards $(9,7,44,1,51,4,6,2,9,10)$, the next player the next ten cards, and so on. There is an action of the cyclic group with five elements induced by cyclicly permuting the players (together with their cards), so applying this symmetry we need five times the probability that the first player gets the four aces. We may and do assume that the aces are the cards $1,2,3,4$. We start finding them a place in a permutation.

- For the good cases $1$ has $10$ good places (in the hand of the first player), then depending on the place of $1$ there are each $9$ places for the $2$, then each $8$ places for the $3$, and finally $7$ places for the $4$. The remained cards can be distributed at the remained $48$ places, so there are $48!$ chances for this. So we have a total of $10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 48!$ good permutations, when the first player gets the four aces.
- The total number of cases is the number of all permutations, $52!=52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48!$, so in contrast to the above counting of the good cases the four aces have each $52$, then $51$, then $50$, then respectively $49$ independent possibilities.

Putting all together, the wanted probability is:
$$
5\times 
\frac
{10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 48!}
{52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48!}
=
5\times 
\frac
{10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7}
{52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49}
=
\frac
{9\cdot 8\cdot 7}
{52\cdot 51\cdot 49}
=
\frac
{9\cdot 8}
{52\cdot 51\cdot 7 }
=
\frac6{1547}
\ .
$$
This is approximatively $0.00387847446670976082740788623\dots $ .

Comment: **In short:** We seek the probability that the aces are placed in *four* among the *ten* cards of *one* among *five* hands, when selecting any *four* among **all** *fifty two* places in the deck (the five hands and the discards).  $$\dfrac{~\dbinom 51~\dbinom{10}4~}{\dbinom{52}{4}}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Yes, this was more or less also my comment to the question some minutes after it appeared, since this was not clear. The OP already wanted the factor $5$, so i usually respect the initial idea, and i had to explain it in some more detail. giving a symmetry argument. Since the permutation group appeared now, it was simpler to write the finish using arrangements.

Answer (score 1):

We can just see how the aces must fall, and forget about the rest.

Imagine $50$ slots for the players + $2$ for discards

The first ace has to fall in one of the $50$ slots, and the rest must fall in the remaining slots of *that* player,

thus Pr = $\frac{50}{52}\frac{9}{51}\frac{8}{50}\frac{7}{49} = \frac{6}{1547}, \approx 0.00388$